# Is it not possible to set arguments that have not been provided, using arguments property

Tags: javascript

I was testing things. And discovered that i could not set arguments if i have not provided it.
Using `arguments[1]` etc.

Example:

```
function abc (a,b) {
arguments[1] = 'new value';
console.log(b);
}
abc('a');
```

It won't work.

I know i could set value like `if (b=='undefined') b='default';` but why i can't like this. In other words this behavior is unexpected, isn't it?

On the other hand, if you do provide argument it will get changed!

calling function like this will output **new value**

```
abc('a','b');
```

is there a solution, if you wanted to set value using `arguments[2]` and pass argument when calling function.

after more testing it seems: `b` doesnt get connected with `arguments[1]` if not called.

Comment: it's verboten in strict mode, though you can get away with it in most browsers in full js...

Comment: explain please i am new to this strict thing

Comment: Use Strict, formerly "Compact Profile" in ecma3, is a way to disable the more powerful/dangerous/misunderstood parts of js to prevent mistakes and browser-specific quirks, like over-writing the arguments object instead of using formal parameter names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is argument is dynamic whose length is set by number of arguments / parameters provided to the function.

In first case, you have provided only one parameter so size of argument is 1 and hence argument[1] should be out of bound, while in second case, you have argument of length 2 so you can change either parameter value by using its index.

Comment: arguments is not an array.

Comment: it behaves like it, and yes i tested this is what's happening as well. arguments.length was 1 even after i set b

Comment: Try various `Array` methods to see that, unfortunately, `arguments` does *not* (yet) behave like an `Array` instance. In particular, it works differently in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

After posting a terribly wrong answer, I took a look at the [ECMA Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) and here is in code, what JavaScript does when the `arguments` object will be created:

```
function abc () {
    var names = ["a", "b"];  //as normally provided in the function declaration: function (a, b)
    var a, b;
    var args = {};
    var mappedNames = [];
    args.length = arguments.length;
    var index = args.length - 1;

    //this is the crucial part. This loop adds properties to the arguments object
    //and creates getter and setter functions to bind the arguments properties to the local variables
    //BUT: the loop only runs for the arguments that are actually passed.
    while (index >= 0) {
        var val = arguments[index];
        if (index < names.length) {
            var name = names[index];
            if (mappedNames.indexOf(name) === -1) {
                mappedNames.push(name);
                var g = MakeArgGetter(name);
                var p = MakeArgSetter(name);
                Object.defineProperty(args, index.toString(), {get : g, set : p, configurable : true});
            }
        } 
        args[index.toString()] = val;
        index--;
    }

    function MakeArgGetter(name) {
        return function zz(){
            return eval(name);
        };
    }

    function MakeArgSetter(name) {
        return function tt(value) {
            eval(name + " = value;");
        };
    }

    console.log(args[0]);   //ab
    args[0] = "hello";  
    args[1] = "hello";
    console.log(a);         //hello      
    console.log(b);         //undefined

}
abc('ab');
```

Note, that there is some more going on in the Spec and I simplyfied it here and there, but this is essentially what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by this?

If you want to have "dynamic arguments" like `abc('a)` and `abc('a', 'b')` are both valid, but the first will set the missing argument to a default value, you either have to check for the arguments length and/or for all arguments values.

Suppose the following: `abc('a', null)` is given, what then? - depends on logic, can be good but can also be bad.

Given this, checking the argument vector isn't smarter but more cryptic and having something like `if (b=='undefined') b='default'` much straighter and better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Not possible per ECMA spec since `arguments` is binded to only formal parameters that match the provided arguments. Its recommended to only reference `arguments` and not alter it.

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/73WfA/2/

---

### About Arguments

The non-strict `arguments` object is a bidirectional and mapped object to *FormalParameterList*, which is a list generated based on the number of provided arguments that map to defined parameters in the target function defintion/expression.

> When control enters an execution context for function code, an arguments object is created unless (as specified in 10.5) the identifier arguments occurs as an Identifier in the function’s FormalParameterList or occurs as the Identifier of a VariableDeclaration or FunctionDeclaration contained in the function code. *ECMA 5.1 spec (as of 03/26/2014)*

### `arguments` to variables / variables to `arguments`

Argument-to-variable mappings exist only internally when the method is invoked. Mappings are immutable and are created when a target function is invoked, per instance. The update bindings between the two is also disabled when the `use strict` flag is available within the scope of the function. `arguments` becomes strictly a reference and no longer a  way to update parameters.

> For non-strict mode functions the array index (defined in 15.4) named data properties of an arguments object whose numeric name values are less than the number of formal parameters of the corresponding function object initially share their values with the corresponding argument bindings in the function’s execution context. This means that changing the property changes the corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa. This correspondence is broken if such a property is deleted and then redefined or if the property is changed into an accessor property. For strict mode functions, the values of the arguments object‘s properties are simply a copy of the arguments passed to the function and there is no dynamic linkage between the property values and the formal parameter values. *ECMA 5.1 spec (as of 03/26/2014)*

### What about `length`?

`arguments.length` can be an indicator initially to determine how many formal parameters were met but it's unsafe since `arguments` can be changed without `length` ever updating automatically. `length` doesn't update because it's not a *real* array and therefore doesn't adhere to the `Array` spec.