# Javascript:What's the differences between formal parameter and arguments object?

Tags: javascript, parameters

Here is the test code:

```
function fn(i, j) {
    arguments = [3, 4];
    console.log(i, j); // 1, 2
    console.log(arguments); // [3, 4]
}

fn(1, 2);
```

in the function , I reset the `arguments` object

However, the arguments object is changed, but the formal parameter which passed in is not chaned, I think they are the same, so what's the differences?

Comment: `function fn(i, j) {
    arguments[0]=3;
    arguments[1]=4;
    console.log(i, j); // 1, 2 Now it is 3,4
    console.log(arguments); // [3, 4]
}`
`fn(1, 2);`
Using array indexes of arguments object Formal arguments can be changed !

Comment: If you are more interested in how the arguments object and the local variables work together, I would recommend you an answer that I posted to a different question in which I TRIED to write in code what's written in the ECMA Specs ([LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17478232/1258878)). In short: it works with getters and setters on the local variables. This should also make clear that you cannot override the entire object without losing this behaviour (like others already correctly posted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments` is an array-like object, which has reference to all the parameters passed to it. Here, you have merely reassigned `arguments` to point to some other object. If you want to change the actual parameters, you have to change the elements of `arguments`, like this

```
function fn(i, j) {
    arguments[0] = -1;
    console.log(i, j);      // -1, 2
    console.log(arguments); // { '0': -1, '1': 2 }
}

fn(1, 2)
```

Quoting from [arguments, MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments#Description)

> The arguments object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array, but
> does not have any Array properties except length. For example, it does
> not have the pop method.
>
> However it can be converted to a real Array:
>
> var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
>
> If Array generics
> are available, one can use the following instead:
>
> var args = Array.slice(arguments);

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the arguments array (actually an array-like object) with a new array. They are separate objects and exist side by side. Replacing the reference of the `arguments` variable doesn't make the function use the new array as arguments, it still has an internal reference to the original object.

If you change the contents of the `arguments` object, it will reflect on the function arguments:

```
function fn(i, j) {
    arguments[0] = 3;
    arguments[1] = 4;
    console.log(i, j); // 3, 4
    console.log(arguments); // [3, 4]
}

fn(1, 2);
```